# Users who keep asking and answering their own questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I was looking at a particular user's profile, and I noticed that on the front page of their answers, at least 9 of them were asked then self-answered.

I read [the post on answering your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). I understand it is fine to answer your own questions, but the sheer number of questions self-answered by this user is strange.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: Are they bad?  If not why does it matter?  Other people can still answer and add more content.

Comment: Would you rather they answered their questions with sock puppets instead?

Comment: if you know it's fine to answer your own question... why does the number of times it happens should be taken in consideration? If it's fine to do it, it's fine to do it :).

Comment: @Servy which point? How does it relate to me saying 'the behavior is okay, so doing it multiple times is okay'. The behavior is 'self-answer a question', not 'post the same question 12 times' as your comment is currently doing. This is a very pedantic point that brings NOTHING to the topic here.

Comment: @Patrice The number of times someone does something *isn't* inherently always irrelevant.  It just happens to not be an issue in this specific instance.  There's a big difference.  Your conclusion doesn't follow from your argument, even though your conclusion isn't wrong.

Comment: which basically comes back to "this is a pedantic point that brings NOTHING to the topic here". Let's just stop that here. I don't feel like pointless argumentation today

Comment: @Patrice - Pointless arguments compose a majority of meta though :) Especially since every single argument here has already taken place and now resides at MSE so we can have each argument again. Meta is the Twilight Zone, a groundhog's day of repetition with only a very slight twist of pedantic nuance thrown in to barely make the repetition vary with time.

Comment: @TravisJ totally true. But I've been trying to not get as wrapped up in those pedantic arguments. Other members can appreciate these arguments if they want. I'm going to try to stay out of them more :p. This was attempt #1 :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the questions are good questions, with good answers, then it's fine.  If they're bad questions, or bad answers, then treat them just like you would any other bad question or bad answer, or any user who is regularly posting bad questions and/or answers.

The fact that the user is answering their own questions is entirely irrelevant.